# Keep Vuex state data without vuex-persist

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuex-persist

weird question but i don't find an answer anywhere..

I return user  data from an API call to Vuex. I save my user object into the Vuex state, along with a Token. (User object and Token are created and send back from Server to Vuex at the same time.)

Everything runs perfect and on the initialization of the component i fetch with a getter the user name etc.

But when i refresh i loose the user object from the state. But, i do not loose the Token. Which is weird cause i create them and return them together.

**The question is, how can i keep the user in the state until i logout?**

- I don't need to keep them in localStorage or inside a cookie cause they are sensitive data (user). I just want to get them through a getter from my store. Which is the correct way to do it.
  **So vuex-persist is not an option..**

Below you see my code:

**store.js:**

```
state: {
    status: '',
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    user: {}
},
mutations: {
    auth_success(state, { token, user }) {
    state.status = 'success';
    state.token = token;
    state.user = user;
},
actions: {
    login({ commit }, user) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('auth_request');
    axios({
          url: 'http://localhost:8085/login',
      data: user,
      method: 'POST'
        .then((resp) => {
           const token = resp.data.token;
           const user = resp.data.user;

           axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;

           commit('auth_success', { token, user });
         })
         .catch((err) => {
           commit('auth_error');
           localStorage.removeItem('token');
           reject(err);
        });
  }
},
getters: {
 isLoggedIn(state) {
  return state.token;
},
getUser(state){
  return state.user;
}
```

**User.vue:**

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      Welcome {{this.user.fullName}}
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
   data: function() {
    return {
    user: {}
   }
  },
   mounted() {
    this.getUser();
  },
 methods: {
    getUser() {
      return (this.user = this.$store.getters.getUser);
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

So to sum up: 
Token stays in Vuex, user data does not. How to keep them in state without local Storage or cookies?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `getUser` computed property should not be modifying reactive state; did you mean for it to be a method?

Comment: Really sorry, i wrote it wrong. It is a method, i will edit my question. Thanks!

Comment: Vue stores data in the memory, when you refresh the page, it is expected to lose all the memory. You can use the router guard, check it at `beforeRouteEnter`, if vuex does not have `user` object, call the `getUser()` again.

Take a look at this demo https://github.com/gothinkster/vue-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/views/ArticleEdit.vue

Comment: @SangĐặng So you say that there is no way to do it.. `getUser()` get's what exists in the state. Which gets filled once you login. Only then.

Comment: The answer below explains pretty good what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, as Sang Đặng mentioned, if you want to have user data in your vuex (without storing it on the user side) you need to fetch them *after every*  refresh. Refreshing the page means that whole Vue application (and your Vuex state) is removed from the memory (user's browser), which causes that you lose your current store data. `token` is also removed from the memory, but you load it on your store initialisation:

```
state: {
  token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  ...
}
```

Because of this you are seeing `token` "kept" in store, while other user data not. There are many ways to fetch user data after refresh - like mentioned `beforeRouteEnter`. Basically if you want to fetch them on the application load, so you can use [Vue.created](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) hook for example. You can also use lazy-loading in your `getUser` method - if there is no user data - fetch them from your API. [Here](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/implicit) you can read more about authentication patterns in SPA - for example using OAuth.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, you did help me a lot to understand the theory behind all this. And also sorry or the late answer. But the main problem in my implementation is, i can't store my user's data from my back-end (express) **because these are generated through my mssql database, when i login**. So actually, i cannot store them somewhere there, but instead call login function all the time. Am i thinking it all wrong?